# Running mapbox-gl-js locally (unable to serve debug page)

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Edit:
Summary, I tried to follow only the steps listed in the below two links as applies to windows:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

https://github.com/stackgl/headless-gl#windows

Here I have reattached the screenshot of the commands that I had problems with:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wIn3.jpg

One more step I took that I should mention is I also did not find the headless gl when I downloaded the repository, when the install headless gl command did not work I manually copied the file and put it in my local copy under the nodemodules directory thinking it would work but it didnt solve anything. I do  think this is related to access issues but I dont know what else I should try to get it working?

Comment: This looks like something which should be opened as an issue over at Github https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js

Comment: To clarify: looks like you're trying to set up a Mapbox-GL-JS development environment? You don't need to do this to just use Mapbox-GL-JS. But yeah, if you have a problem with the headless-gl dependency, you should just raise that as an issue in the Mapbox-GL-JS repo.

Comment: @SteveBennett yes I brought up the issue with them here https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/7772 they closed it, they said they dont have the resources to help, the problem I have is here: https://media.giphy.com/media/iYmyUZMVECfdyoeHRE/giphy.gif  I am outputting the description of the extrusion to the tooltip. It is not appearing on the extrusion as I would like, but at its location point on the map. there were also other people having the same issue. Mapbox said if I use master I will be able to access their debug script. It would be amazing if you can help me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clarify your problem: you want a version of mapbox-gl.js which contains a recently fixed bug.

Your best option is to just wait a couple of weeks for a release.

Failing that, you should build your own, from master. You don't need to set up a debug server for that. You can skip straight to the "Creating a Standalone Build" section.

If the steps for building on Windows don't work for some reason, you could set up a local virtual machine running Ubuntu and use that.

But honestly, just wait a couple of weeks. :)

Comment: That is my main problem. I revised the original post to be more concise and provide all the details. Thank you for your advice, although I am still confused: you say I should skip to the "creating a standalone build section" I didnt run those steps because I never got passed the command to install the headless dependencies. Are you saying this command is not essential to getting what I want to work ? : copy node_modules/headless-gl/deps/windows/dll/x64/*.dll c:\windows\system32

Comment: I don't know. I haven't tried. But in your shoes, I would try skipping it.

Comment: I tried skipping it.  I moved entire repo to xampp localhost, I changed the links to the scripts from relative to absolute paths there is another script that links to a user generated access code. I ran the file extrusion-query.html, Instead of all the 404 errors I had before I recieve three errors of type 'not allowed to load local resource' and one error of type 'mapbox-gl is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case some one else need to run this on local server.
After clone

1. Run npm install
2. npm run start-debug
   It will start listening on port 9966.

Test the debug html files entering to
localhost:9966/debug/FILE_NAME_TO_TEST.html